# Ionic 2 deeplinking

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, deep-linking

I am running:

```
ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp
```

and I am getting

```
Error: Variable(s) missing (use: --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=value --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=value).
```

I understand that I am missing the two params here but in DEEPLINK_SCHEME I have to specify https and in DEEPLINK_HOST my domain. Problem is that I dont have any website for my project. It is just app based. Am I missing something on how do deep-links work? Thought you dont need a website for apps only

Comment: You do not need a website. Imagine that your mobile user clicks a link on a mobile device (in an email, chat or browser) and instead of the browser your installed app will be opened. That is what deeplinks really mean.

Answer (score 0):

you are putting it wrong into your console. Put on a text editor and make it inline.

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=http --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=myapp.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/
```